# Leave-one-out cross-validation in h2o

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation, h2o

I would like to check result of leave-one-out cross-validation for my quite small df in h2o. This is my input df: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UiIkxlHCq1tJZNOH6hQD30gEMaPdmhgh/view?usp=sharing

Is it possible to set nfolds (i.e. nfolds=nrow(df)) parameter in h2o to get such cross-validation?
I can't set nfolds > 25 for nrow(df)=69.

```
u$dc=as.factor(u$dc)
train <- as.h2o(u)
model <- h2o.gbm(x= colnames(train)[1:15],
                y="dc", training_frame=train,
                nfolds = 25,
                learn_rate = 0.06,
                ntrees = 90, max_depth = 3,   
                min_rows = 2,
                distribution = "bernoulli")
```

I get exception in the above code:

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException:
     Not enough data to create 25 random cross-validation splits. Either reduce nfolds, specify a larger dataset
```

It is thrown in ModelBuilder.java:

```
    at hex.ModelBuilder.cv_makeWeights(ModelBuilder.java:357)
    at hex.ModelBuilder.computeCrossValidation(ModelBuilder.java:276)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$1.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:207)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1263)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the supplied dataset which has 69 examples, you would need the following arguments in the `h2o.gbm` call:

```
nfolds = 69,
fold_assignment = "Modulo"
```

For example, this full code block runs your example with leave-one-out cross validation and includes some extra lines to confirm the folds were assigned properly:

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init(strict_version_check = FALSE)

u$dc=as.factor(u$dc)
train <- as.h2o(u)
model <- h2o.gbm(x= colnames(train)[1:15],
                 y="dc", training_frame=train,
                 nfolds = 69,
                 fold_assignment = "Modulo",
                 keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE, # keep track of fold assignment to confirm leave-one-out
                 learn_rate = 0.06,
                 ntrees = 90, max_depth = 3,   
                 min_rows = 2,
                 distribution = "bernoulli")

folds <- h2o.cross_validation_fold_assignment(model) # get fold assignments
print(folds, n = 69) # print all assignment for the 69 folds
print(h2o.dim(h2o.unique(folds))) # count the number of unique values
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know fold_assignment parameter which can be quite useful.